# How to make a desktop shortcut for .sh script on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I have a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian 11 Bullseye and I want to make a desktop shortcut for a shell script. I have tried a handful of options so far such as making a .desktop file and using the Main Menu Editor, but nothing seems to work. Is it possible to create a desktop shortcut (that a user can just double click on) for a shell script? I just want to make it easier so that the user doesn't have to open a terminal and type `./run_application.sh`

Answer (score 0):

This what I do

1 Right click on the desktop and select 'New file'.

2 Enter a name for the new file. Click OK.

3 Open this new (empty) file in a text editor.

4 Paste your script into this.

5 Make sure the file has the right shebang/hashbang at the top like `#!/bin/bash` or whatever it should be.

6 Save the file from the editor.

7 Right click the icon on the desktop and choose 'Properties'.

8 In 'Properties', ignore 'General' tab and go to the 'Permissions' tab.

9 In Access Control make these settings as needed. I use these:

View Content: Only Owner
Change Content: Only Owner
Execute: Only owner

10 Click OK.

After this the script should run when you double click the icon, if it has not got any errors.

Comment: Thank you @Michael Harvey, is there a way to change it icon ?

Answer (score 0):

Open the File Manager, navigate to your desired shell script, and left-mouse drag it to your desktop.  This will create a shortcut, rather than creating a new script that is stored on your desktop (and potentially doubling your effort whenever you want to update your script).